# Сравнение значения списка с индексами другого двумерного списка

Tags: python, python-3.x

Имеется двумерный список у которого количество больших списков равняется инпуту(n=3) от пользователя :

```
l1=[]
n=int(input())
for i in range(n) :
    l1.append([])
    for s in range(1):
        l1[i].append(0)
print(l1)
```

в общем : вот `l1=[[0], [0], [0]]` 
его нужно сравнить с другим списком(он уже статичный).
Например : `[1, 3, 3, 1]` но мне нужно не сравнивать с самими значениями списка,а сравнивать с индексом.Например если первое число 1 оно равно индексу в списке(`l1`) под номером 1,значит надо добавить +1 в значение этого индекса.

Входные

```
3
1331
```

Выходные

```
2 0 2
```

Comment: ничего непонятно, добавьте пример входных и выходных данных

Comment: правил , надеюсь понятно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно я понял что вам нужно?

```
number = [0, 0, 0]
l1 = [1, 3, 3, 1]

for i in l1:
    number[i-1] += 1

print(number)  # [2, 0, 2]
```

---

```
number = [[0], [0], [0]]
l1 = [1, 3, 3, 1]

for i in l1:
    number[i-1][0] += 1

print(number)  # [[2], [0], [2]]

number = [i[0] for i in number]
print(number)  # [2, 0, 2]
```

Comment: А как сделать чтобы он работал также но с таким видом?`[[0], [0], [0]]`

Comment: @DoubleMid, обновил ответ